# Issue understanding linker error. Missing library?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, linker, clang

I'm working on a project that was made 2 years ago. The idea is to port it to iPad Mini and iPhone 5. But I can't even compile it on Xcode 4.5.2 and I'm guessing it has something to do with the old iOS it was made for. 
Can someone help me understand this error message?

> Ld /Users/luisharo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HomeBroker-dzpamgfducpqanemuwqzgjkjwoka/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HomeBroker.app/HomeBroker normal i386
>       cd /Users/luisharo/Mobiik/GBM/gbm-homebroker-iphone/HomeBroker
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/luisharo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HomeBroker-dzpamgfducpqanemuwqzgjkjwoka/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/luisharo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HomeBroker-dzpamgfducpqanemuwqzgjkjwoka/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/luisharo/Mobiik/GBM/gbm-homebroker-iphone/HomeBroker -filelist /Users/luisharo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HomeBroker-dzpamgfducpqanemuwqzgjkjwoka/Build/Intermediates/HomeBroker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HomeBroker.build/Objects-normal/i386/HomeBroker.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lgcov -fobjc-link-runtime -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 -framework MessageUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework QuartzCore -lxml2 -o /Users/luisharo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HomeBroker-dzpamgfducpqanemuwqzgjkjwoka/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HomeBroker.app/HomeBroker
>
> ld: library not found for -lgcov
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message:

> ld: library not found for -lgcov clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

There could be two problems:

1. you don't have gcov library
2. your gcov library is in a different location then it was before

If you don't have gcov library at all install it.

If you have gcov library make sure that the linker sees it, use:

```
-Lpath/to/libgcov
```